# How to add specific bower components as IE8 conditional block in Gulp

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, gulp, wiredep, gulp-inject

I have several bower components, of which I need some components like `json3`, `respondjs`, `es5shim` to be added in an IE8 conditional block (in build as well as serve) like this :

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/json3.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->`

How should I proceed to write the task? I could not find any suitable examples with `gulp-inject` as well as `wiredep` for this issue. Please advise

Comment: Can't figure out a way outside of ignorign those files/components with wiredep and adding that conditional block and its content manually to HTML.

Comment: yes currently I have just kept the script tags in conditional statements hardcoded. What I want is a dynamic way to do so by gulp plugin

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) and [gulp-inject's starttag option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#method-1-use-gulp-inject-s-starttag-option).

Suppose you have the following injections defined in `index.html`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<![endif]-->
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

You can wire them in gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var gulpInject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
    var ie8Files = ['**/json3.js', '**/es5shim.js'];
    // the same as: var restFiles = ['*', '!**/json3.js', '!**/es5shim.js'];
    var restFiles = ['*'].concat(ie8Files.map(function(e) { return '!' + e;}));
    return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(gulpInject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}).pipe(gulpFilter(restFiles))))
    .pipe(gulpInject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}).pipe(gulpFilter(ie8Files)),
                    {starttag: '<!--[if lt IE 9]>', endtag: '<![endif]-->'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Which results in (for example):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="bower_components/json3/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/shim/es5shim.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.