# I keep getting Object.create error in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, bower, vis.js

I have an AngularJs web-app using [vis.js](http://visjs.org), which is compatible with IE9+, but I'm trying to make this web-app compatible with IE8 with less features avaiable for the user, **because I have to**.

I included the following libraries to handle the common IE8 compatibility issues:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/eventShim.js"></script>
      <script>
// here I create the elements for all the custom directives
        document.createElement('custom-handler');
        document.createElement('custom-info');
        document.createElement('custom-data');
        document.createElement('custom-param');
        document.createElement('custom-rel');
        document.createElement('custom-panel');

        // Optionally these for CSS
        document.createElement('ng:include');
        document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng:view');
        document.createElement('ng:style');
        document.createElement('ng:class');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

And then using bower:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Notable versions of the libraries defined within the **bower.json**:

```
"angular": "1.2",
"jquery": "1.11.2",
"json3": "~3.3.2",
"es5-shim": "~4.1.11",
"bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.5",
"angular-animate": "~1.2.0",
"angular-cookies": "~1.2.0",
"angular-resource": "~1.2.0",
"angular-route": "~1.2.0",
"angular-sanitize": "~1.2.0",
"angular-touch": "~1.2.0",
"angular-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
"vis": "~3.7.2",
"string": "~3.0.0",
"components-font-awesome": "~4.4.0",
"jquery-ui": "~1.11.4"
```

> **The problem**

Despite all of the above settings, when I access my web-app using IE8, I get the following error in console:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method        vis.min.js, line 29 character 1204
```

And by clicking it, the console puts the cursor at the beginning of the following line of code:

```
s.prototype=Object.create(o.prototype),s.prototype.redraw=function(...
```

The error persists even if I comment the HTML parts where vis.js is used.

I wasn't able to find a way in bower to include the vis.js library just when the web-app is opened in IE9+, so my *B plan* was to just get rid of the errors related to vis.js and then make unavaiable all the features in the web-app which make use of this library.

**This approach could work?**

**If not, how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wasn't able to find a way in bower to include the vis.js library just when the web-app is opened in IE9+

**Bower** could only include sources.
For such a tasks a **gulp** was created.
For example your building would exist with such a code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var gulpInject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
    var ie8Files = ['**/json3.js', '**/es5shim.js'];
    // the same as: var restFiles = ['*', '!**/json3.js', '!**/es5shim.js'];
    var restFiles = ['*'].concat(ie8Files.map(function(e) { return '!' + e;}));
    gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(gulpInject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}).pipe(restFiles))
    .pipe(gulpInject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}).pipe(ie8Files),
                    {starttag: '<!--[if lt IE 9]>', endtag: '<![endif]-->'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794237/how-to-add-specific-bower-components-as-ie8-conditional-block-in-gulp)

Or as you said plan B:

you can write all cycles for your code like that one:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(o, properties) {
        if (typeof o !== 'object' && typeof o !== 'function') throw new TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object: ' + o);
        else if (o === null) throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support 'null' as the first argument.");

        if (typeof properties != 'undefined') throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support a second argument.");

        function F() {}

        F.prototype = o;

        return new F();
    };
}
```

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020265/object-create-not-supported-in-ie8)

For my opinion you should add a gulp constructions.

Comment: Hi Illia, I'm using Grunt, do you know how to implement your Gulp based solution in Grunt?
For the B plan, I came across that same `Object.create` polyfill and knew that would have been my ace in the hole; however, should I include it within a `<script>` inside the `index.html` page or should I include it within a separate .js file?

Comment: I guess its not your job to make IE act like it dont supposed to act. Its weird  that es5-shim doesnt work so far. But how about really add a **gulp** into project? Or is it just not an option?

Comment: Its easy you dont have to translate one into another, use a plugin [grunt-gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-gulp)

Comment: I appreciate that suggestion, but it seems I have another ace in the hole to keep here, since I really should be able to solve this situation using just what I have, again **because I have to do so**.

Comment: What about plan B i am a besider of a way that html contains html (ok or template, hello __angular__) and js contains js. Much of projects have some `utils.js` or kind of that.